# Android InAppBrowser _system callbacks

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, callback, inappbrowser

I have been developing a mobile app for Android/IOS/Windows 8 in Cordova that needs to pass a few strings to a web page. Unfortunately for me, the web page does not support TLS 1.0 protocol, which means older Android versions (and IOS versions) cannot open the page within the native browser.

This means the window.open call, when set to '_blank', will not load the page on any Android version before 16 API, and it's only really guaranteed for 19 API and above:

```
window.open('https://www.libertymountain.com/login.aspx','_blank')
```

My solution was to change it to "_system" instead of "_blank". This works, because the phone can use the chrome or safari browser instead of the native browser. However, when I do this, all of the callbacks cease to work. It just opens up the page, and I can't run the script on it.

For example, the code below does NOT ever execute the callback. It merely opens the webpage:

```
var ref = window.open('https://www.libertymountain.com/login.aspx','_system');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert("Hello"); });
```

Am I missing something, or is there a proper way to do this?

EDIT: Just to make it clear, this is my code that never triggers the callback:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);

function init() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
    var ref = window.open('https://www.libertymountain.com/login.aspx', '_system');
    // This event never triggers, nor does any other event, even though the
    // webpage is opened in Chrome
    websiteReference.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { console.log('Hello'); });
}
```

If I change it to this, the events do trigger. But I need to do it with '_system' otherwise older Android and IOS devices won't be able to do it.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);

function init() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
    // Change '_system' to '_blank'
    var ref = window.open('https://www.libertymountain.com/login.aspx', '_blank');
    // This event never triggers, nor does any other event, even though the
    // webpage is opened in Chrome
    websiteReference.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { console.log('Hello'); });
}
```

Comment: @jcesarmobile You can? How? The listeners are not triggering for the external browser.

Comment: Sorry, it was "you can't add listeners to external browsers"

Comment: @jcesarmobile So is there any way to run a script on the external browser on the phone?

Comment: No, it's not possible

Comment: @jcesarmobile Alright, that's what I needed to hear. I'm surprised this was so difficult to find out. The documentation says nothing about external browsers not being able to trigger callbacks or have scripts executed on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard that you can't actually execute scripts or trigger callbacks in the external system browsers (when using the '_system' option for InAppBrowser window.open()). From my testing, this seems to be true. On the other hand, '_blank' does of course trigger callbacks because it is using the native browser within the app.

Comment: This has certainly been my experience - _system seems to be more or less fire and forget. At least until it conflicts with other _blank or _self windows you may have opened in the mean time.

I actually wonder why they bundled _system in - its behaviour is so different

Answer (score 0):

In order to run script on another file you need to load that file first like this:-

```
var ref = window.open('http://www.libertymountain.com/','_system');
$(ref .document).load(function() {
    alert('Hello');
    // do other things
});
```

**OR +-------**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
     var ref = window.open('http://www.libertymountain.com/','_system');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('Hello'); });
}
```

Comment: I tried the second one already. The callback only triggers if you change '_system' to '_blank'. As I explained in my post, this is a problem because I need to use '_system' so that old Android/IOS devices can use a different browser to log into the website.