# Cordova InAppBrowser - Event callbacks not called after opening system browser ("_system")

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

In our Cordova app we're using an InAppBrowser (don't we all?) to run our local web app. Occasionally we need to open the device's browser (Chrome / Safari) to handle outside links.

When we come back from the device browser it seems that the InAppBrowser plugin stops triggering events (`'loadstop'`, `'loadstart'`, etc...). We've tried re-registering the events but this doesn't seem to work.

Anyone knows why?

### Here Be Tech Info

We're opening our local webapp the usual way:

```
ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, 'blank', options);
```

No surprises either on registering the events' callbacks:

```
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', onLoadStop);
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', onLoadStart);
ref.addEventListener('loaderror', onLoadError);
ref.addEventListener('exit', onExit);
```

We've tried opening the external web browser using `window`:

```
window.open(event.url, '_system');
```

Or using a second InAppBrowser:

```
var browser = new cordova.InAppBrowser.open(event.url,'_system');
```

We're using [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) v3.0.0. This happens both on Android ad iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a [known issue with InAppBrowser](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13198): opening the system browser causes the events dispatcher to malfunction.

The official solution is to register the same event callbacks with the new InAppBrowser. Since InAppBrowser does [not trigger events at all for the system browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420935/android-inappbrowser-system-callbacks), you do not need to worry about triggering double event callbacks. This solution restores event handling to the old (local webapp) InAppBrowser.

Example from the official issue:

```
//example 3 : hack/solution with cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_system');
//event hander for inAppBrowser
function inAppBrowserEventHandler(event){
  //process few logic with the event parameter
  //and if conditions met lets open it on system browser
  var url = 'https://cordova.apache.org/';

  //open the url in system browser
  var _inAppBrowserSystem = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_system');

   //for somereason, after assigning the same event handler to the _inAppBrowserSystem, the event dispatcher continues to work
  _inAppBrowserSystem.addEventListener('loadstop', inAppBrowserEventHandler);
}
//open the link in inside the iAB without
var _inAppBrowser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank');
_inAppBrowser.addEventListener('loadstop', inAppBrowserEventHandler);
```